# Every derived table must have its own alias #1248

Tags: mysql

I am running this query on MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE DuplicateSKU 
SELECT * FROM FeedsAll
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT FeedsAll.SKU
    FROM FeedsAll
    GROUP BY FeedsAll.SKU
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as DuplicateSKU;
```

and it is giving this error:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

What is wrong?

**Help, please!**

Answer (score 0):

You are using the name `DuplicateSKU` twice, once for the new table once for your subquery. These should be different names, e.g.

```
create table duplicatesku 
select * 
from feedsall 
inner join 
( 
  select sku 
  from feedsall 
  group by sku 
  having count(*) > 1
) as duplicates on duplicates.sku = feedsall.sku;
```

By the way you were cross-joining (missing ON clause, which MySQL doesn't report unfortunately). I added the appropriate ON clause.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I am trying: CREATE TABLE DuplicateSKU 
SELECT * 
from FeedsAll 
inner join 
( 
  select SKU 
  from FeedsAll 
  group by SKU 
  having count(*) > 1
) as duplicates on DuplicateSKU.SKU = FeedsAll.SKU; but error message #1054 - Unknown column 'DuplicateSKU.SKU' in 'on clause'. What does this mean?

Comment: That's not the query I posted :-) It must be `on Duplicates.SKU` not `on DuplicateSKU.SKU`.

Comment: I've tryed -  result same

Comment: So your query does no longer contain `DuplicateSKU.SKU`, but your DBMS says Unknown column 'DuplicateSKU.SKU'??? I doubt that.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'Duplicates.SKU' in 'on clause'

Comment: But in your subquery you select `sku` and you name the subquery `duplicates`, then `duplicates.sku` must be available. As it is unlikely that MySQL is that broken, it must be you having made a mistake in your query. Did you try my query without any modification already?